# component/element are not properly placed to each other and impact the other element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am building a home page and in this webpage, I have to display an image with text, paragraphe, button and an icon.

this is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

And this is what I have:

[image]

I was able to make it works a few days ago but I realize that all the layout/css... was so complicated that my entire page was messed-up. So to prevent, any more complications, I have rebuild the page from the ground, by adding text then replace text by a content and make sure that all is fitting well.

As you can see the texte/title/icon/button are not on the image, it's all over the place. Perhaps, I need to use a `div` and the image as background.

I notice that it happened in the past that the element text, button,... placement which are supposed to by on top of the image, can move aroung sometimes and impacted by other element.

I am adding the code below :

```
import React from 'react';

import VillageBanner from '../assets/images/village-banner-icon.png';
import DiscoverImage from '../assets/images/discover-home.jpg';
import WhiteButton from '../components/materialdesign/WhiteButton';
import BlueButton from '../components/materialdesign/BlueButton';
import HomeCarousel from '../components/HomeCarousel';
import Slider from '../components/materialdesign/VillageSlider';

import TextContents from '../assets/translations/TextContents';


import './Home.css';

class Home extends React.Component {
    
    render() {
        const TheWorldIsYours = 
            <div className="home-full-section">
                <div>
                    <img
                        src= { DiscoverImage }
                        className= "home-discover-background"
                        alt="Village"
                        />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div className="home-discover-text-container">
                        <h1>{TextContents.ThinkOfUs}</h1>
                        <p>{TextContents.TheWorldIsYours}</p>
                        <div className="button-discover">
                            <WhiteButton textSize="14" link_href="/discover" text={TextContents.DiscoverBtn} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <img
                        src= { VillageBanner }
                        className = "home-discover-banner"
                        alt="Village"
                    />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>;

            const CuratedLearning = 
                    <div className="home-section">
                        <h1>{TextContents.CuratedTitle}</h1>
                        <p>{TextContents.CuratedDesc}</p>
                        <BlueButton textSize="14" link_href="/hereisthemission" text={TextContents.HereIsBtn} />
                    </div>;

            const WhatsTrending = 
                    <div className="home-section">
                        <h1>{TextContents.TrendTitle}</h1>
                    </div>

            const WhatsNearby = 
                    <div className="home-section">
                        <h1>{TextContents.NearbyTitle}</h1>
                    </div>


        return (
            <div className="home-container">
                <div>
                    {TheWorldIsYours}
                </div>
                <div>
                    {CuratedLearning}
                </div>
                <div>
                    {WhatsTrending}
                    <div>
                        <HomeCarousel />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="add-space">
                    {WhatsNearby}
                    <div>
                        <Slider />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                );
        }
}

export default Home;
```

and the asssociated css is :

```
.home-discover-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 21.5px;
}

.home-discover-background {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 21.5px;
}

.home-discover-text-container {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    text-align-last: left;
    top: 35%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 20%;
    right: 0;
}

.home-discover-text-container h1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 25rem;
    font-family: Fredoka One;
    font-size: 2,5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: left;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.home-discover-text-container p {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: #ffffffff;
}




.home-container {
    margin-bottom:5rem;
}

.home-full-section {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom:4rem;
    width: 100%;
}


/* tablet, ipad  version (change font-size here if needed)*/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px){
    .home-discover-text-container h1 {
        font-size: 34px;
    }
    .home-discover-text-container p {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
}

/* mobile version (change font-size here if needed)*/
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .home-discover-text-container, .home-discover-text-container h1, .home-discover-text-container p{
        width: calc(100% - 20%); /* subtract the left:20% of .text-tile in desktop-version  and set full width */
    }
    .home-discover-text-container h1 {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    .home-discover-text-container p {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}

.home-discover-banner {
    width: 54px;
    height: 82px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    top: 35.5%;a
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 15%; 
    right: 0;
}

.button-discover {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    top: 38%;
}

.button-curated {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    top: 32%;
}
```

So what I am trying to achieve is to get the image, title, text, icon and button seen as a single element where the overall design stay as is and for responsivness, keeping almost the same design except that probably the font must be changed to keep it nice

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside of a div and set the image as backgroung-image in css. You can also use position: absolute on the child and position: relative on the parent and some top: left: spacing to make it look nice.

Comment: I am not able to show the image in bkg. using this command `    background-image: url(../assets/images/discover-home.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
`